# onBlur on editable-form (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

Is there a directive onblur for editable-form? I can't seem to find one. angular has this ngTouch but it only validates a single input. What I really want is to know if the user loses focus on the form itself.

my code is something like this [editable-form][1]
but when the user clicks on the different form the editable form will trigger the `editableForm.$cancel()` method.

**http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/81/**

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: thanks for the response @adeel_s but i already got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution, you only need to add the tag `blur='cancel'` on `<form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="saveUser()" blur="cancel">`